# Performing action based on ObjectAtIndex on a UIViewController from a NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsmutablearray

Here's an interesting question. I have an application where I have a `JSON` file, the app pings several "Objects" defined by this JSON file. The application does this on a `UITableViewController`. However, I am building an `AtAGlance` view to show objects that failed the ping test. This `AtAGlance` actually will live on the very first VC. That being said, I have everything setup in terms of serializing the `JSON` and I'm getting good values. However, I'm not sure how to specify the `ObjectAtIndex` to send the ping. Any thoughts on how I can specify an `objectAtIndex` from an array on a `UIViewController`? This may be a pretty dumb question, but I've tried everything for these past few days.

Here's some code for you to look at, let me know if you need any additional code.

```
self.objectsList = [[NSArray alloc] init];
[[HTTPServices instance] getConnectabilityObject:^(NSArray * _Nullable dataArray, NSString * _Nullable errorMessage) {
    if (dataArray) {
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (NSDictionary *dictonary in dataArray) {
            ConnectabilityObject *object                = [[ConnectabilityObject alloc] init];
            object.ConnectabilityTitle                  = [dictonary objectForKey:@"ConnectabilityObjectTitle"];
            object.ConnectabilityFullIPAddress          = [dictonary objectForKey:@"ConnectabilityObjectFullIPAddress"];
            object.ConnectabilityObjectLastOctet        = [dictonary objectForKey:@"ConnectabilityObjectLastOctet"];
            object.ConnectabilityObjectType             = [dictonary objectForKey:@"ConnectabilityObjectType"];
            object.ConnectabilityObjectPortNumberOne    = [dictonary objectForKey:@"ConnectabilityObjectPortNum1"];
            object.ConnectabilityObjectPortNumberTwo    = [dictonary objectForKey:@"ConnectabilityObjectPortNum2"];
            object.ConnectabilityObjectPortNumberThree  = [dictonary objectForKey:@"ConnectabilityObjectPortNum3"];
            [array addObject:object];
        }
        self.objectsList = array;
    } else if (errorMessage) {
        UIAlertController *errorAlert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Uh oh" message:@"We just had a crash landing into the nest. We couldn't grab the connectivity file...try again later" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction *dismissAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Okay" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *dismiss){
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }];
        [errorAlert addAction:dismissAction];
        [self presentViewController:errorAlert animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}];
```

Comment: so you want to perform a different action for everyobject in your array ? Like 10 different actions for an array having 10 objects ?

Comment: I will need to perform a ping per object via the `ConnectabilityObjectFullIPAddress`. Not necessarily an action, the action would just be a single ping to determine the object is up or not. But the ping class is based on a `NSString`, but doesn't work because of no specified index. This works just fine on my `TableViewController`.